# Broken Reference in WDK 8.1 Printer Extension Sample

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, printing, driver, wdk

I've installed Visual Studio 2013 Premium and the WDK 8.1 Update, unfortunately though, when I open the Printer Extension Sample ([https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Printer-extension-sample-0e3e1562][1]) from the WDK samples pack, the reference to PrinterExtensionLib is broken.

I'm sure there must be a prerequisite I'm missing somewhere, but I've got the latest .Net, latest updates to Visual Studio and the latest WDK 8.1, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I've placed the sample project in c:\apps as the sample tells you to do, but still not joy.

Does any body know what I'm missing / haven't installed?

Comment: Try installing WDK 8.1 first.

Comment: @Erfankam Good idea, I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've just spun up a Windows 8 VM and the reference seems to be satisfied, so I guess you can only build some of these samples on a Windows 8 Machine. The sample states that it should be run on Windows 8, but I didn't see build machine requirements.

So, I guess the answer is, I was missing Windows 8 (Yuk).

Comment: I dont think so, because it s mentioned in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454513.aspx) that you can use WDK 8.1 for Windows 8.1, 8 and 7. So, that s not the problem.